# Convert SQL code to linq (LIKE, SELECT)

Tags: sql, linq, ef-code-first

How can I do the following sql code with linq?

SQL;

```
   SELECT BusinessEntityID, FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS "FullName" 
FROM Person WHERE FullName LIKE  'a%'
```

LINQ;

```
 using(var db= new db_Context)
 {
      var query = db.Person.Select(q=> q.FirstName  + " "+ q=>q.FullName)
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching after concatenate the strings is not a good idea. I recommend the search for firstname and lastname separately

```
var query = db.Person.Where (t => t.FirstName.StartsWith("a") || t.LastName.StartsWith("a") )
                     .Select(q=> new { q.BusinessEntityID, Fullname = q.FirstName  + " " + q.LastName })
```

Comment: With your condition person like "tom anderson" will be returned, but it is not starts with "a" letter.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49364735/join-with-comma-separated-values-in-sql-server-linq/49366114#49366114 Serkan abi bu soruda da yardım edebilir misin?

Comment: @yuksel I will try.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will be helpful to you,

```
var list1 =  db.Person.Where (t => t.FirstName.StartsWith("a"))
                     .Select(q=> new { 
                             BusinessEntityID = q.BusinessEntityID, 
                             Fullname = q.FirstName + " " + q.LastName 
                      });
```

**Or**

```
var list2 = from psn in db.Person
            where psn.FirstName.StartsWith("a")
            select new {
                  BusinessEntityID = psn.BusinessEntityID, 
                  Fullname = psn.FirstName + " " + psn.LastName 
            };
```